# XFCE: Default mode when conntecting a second display

Tags: xfce, multi-monitor

Whenever I plug in a second monitor, XFCE (most recent version from Arch) will default to mirror the primary screen to it.

Is it possible to alter this default, i.e. can I make it extend the workspace to the secondary screen directly? Right now I need to use `xfce4-display-setting` to switch to this mode manually. This is kinda annoying (and exposes the primary screen's content for a moment).

Answer (score 1):

This is not real answer but just info about bug filed because this seems to be an bug of xfce.

I am using XFCE-4.12.1 now (Fedora 26 XFCE) and after pluging another display it just do the corrupted version of mirror screen (there is primary screen mirrored on the plugged display but the panels are moved to plugged display too which is not normal when using mirror screen).

When openinig the `/usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings` there is no Mirror option checked but the screen shows mirrored display. When opening `/usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings -m` (minimal interface) it's in mirror mode.

After searching on the internets I decided to report it as an xfce bug at their bugzilla here https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13721, feel free to check for more details and screenshots there.

Comment: looking at the xfce4-settings/dialogs/display-settings/main.c it seems that the mirror mode is selected by Fedora itself, not by the xfce. Will investigate further.